# MySQL-Assigning Foreign key

Tags: mysql

I would like to create 3 tables which are student table, lecturer table and course table.
Each student table and lecturer table has course_code column which references to course table.
however, i could assign this foreign key for studen-course table, but it does not work for lecturer-course table.

### It prompts out:

ERROR 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-5e4_5'
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `test`.`lecturer` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `course_code`
  FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`course` (`course_code`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION

### ON UPDATE NO ACTION

Is anyone can help me ?
Thanks a lot !!

Student table
 - student_id varchar(10) PK;
 - student_name varchar(30);
 - course_code varchar(10);
 - Foreign key (course_code) references course table (course_code);

Lecturer table
 - lecturer_id varchar(10)PK;
 - lecturer_name varchar(30);
 - course_code varchar(10);
 - Foreign key (course_code) references course table (course_code);

Course table
 - course_code varchar(10) PK;
 - course_name varchar(10);